# How can I get the BALANCE for every row using the query below

Tags: mysql

I want to get the balance for every Debit and Credit then calculate the balance per row..

```
SELECT SUM(IF(s.AMT>0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) AS DEBIT,
       SUM(IF(s.AMT<0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) * -1 AS CREDIT
FROM
  sldtl AS s
LEFT JOIN
  transtype
ON
  transtype.TransTypeID = s.TR_CODE
WHERE
  s.SL_BRCODE= 1 AND s.SL_CLIENTID= 267 AND s.SLC_CODE= 13 AND s.SLT_CODE= 15 AND 
  s.REF_NO= s.REF_NO AND s.TR_DATE >= (SELECT s.TR_DATE FROM sldtl AS s ORDER BY s.TR_DATE DESC LIMIT 1)-INTERVAL 6 MONTH
GROUP BY
  s.TR_DATE DESC, s.TR_CODE, s.TR_CTLNO
```

needed result

```
 +-----------+--------------+---------------+
 |    DEBIT  |    CREDIT    |    BALANCE    |
 +-----------+--------------+---------------+
 |      0.00 |       700.00 |       -700.00 |
 |      0.00 |       700.00 |      -1400.00 |
 |    400.00 |         0.00 |      -1000.00 |
 |   2000.00 |       500.00 |        500.00 |
 +-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: post your sample data

Comment: what do you mean sir?  that's the result of my query above. but without the balance column sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the simplified version of your problem:

A table containing only `debit` and `credit` columns. And you want to calculate the `balance` column:

**balanceTable:**

```
 debit    credit
   0        700 
   0        700
 400          0
2000        500


SELECT 
debit,
credit,
@balance := @balance + debit - credit AS balance
FROM balancetable, (SELECT @balance := 0) var;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c21c/1/0)

So in your case it would be like:

```
SELECT 
t.DEBIT,
t.CREDIT,
@balance := @balance + t.DEBIT - t.CREDIT AS BALANCE
FROM 
(
    SELECT SUM(IF(s.AMT>0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) AS DEBIT,
                 SUM(IF(s.AMT<0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) * -1 AS CREDIT
    FROM
        sldtl AS s
    LEFT JOIN
        transtype
    ON
        transtype.TransTypeID = s.TR_CODE
    WHERE
        s.SL_BRCODE= 1 AND s.SL_CLIENTID= 267 AND s.SLC_CODE= 13 AND s.SLT_CODE= 15 AND 
        s.REF_NO= s.REF_NO AND s.TR_DATE >= (SELECT s.TR_DATE FROM sldtl AS s ORDER BY s.TR_DATE DESC LIMIT 1)-INTERVAL 6 MONTH
    GROUP BY
        s.TR_DATE DESC, s.TR_CODE, s.TR_CTLNO 
) AS t , (SELECT @balance := 0) var;
```

Comment: yes, this the query that I needed. thank you sir for helping me out. God Bless you always. :D

Comment: You are most welcome. Sounds good that it worked for you. God bless you too.

Comment: Sir I notice when I try to replace WHERE s.TR_DATE >= CURDATE(), then remove the DESC in GROUP BY s.TR_DATE. the result will not be the same in BALANCE column. what should I do Sir to correct the balances sir?

Comment: Actually I didn't concentrate on your query. I just focused on achieving the expected output from your query. What trouble you are in right now may deviate from the context of this particular question. I suggest to post your current situation as a separate question providing with your schema, sample input , expected output and your query. Only then we can help you out hopefully.

Comment: Sir this is the question I asked yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/q/37981402/6122470

Answer (score 1):

What about add @balance at end of your select:

```
SELECT @debit : = SUM(IF(s.AMT>0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) AS DEBIT,
    @credit := SUM(IF(s.AMT<0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) * -1 AS CREDIT,
    @balance := @balance - @credit + @debit As BALANCE
FROM sldtl AS s
LEFT JOIN transtype ON transtype.TransTypeID = s.TR_CODE
JOIN (SELECT @balance := 0) AS tmp
WHERE s.SL_BRCODE = 1 
AND s.SL_CLIENTID = 267 
AND s.SLC_CODE = 13 
AND s.SLT_CODE = 15 
AND s.REF_NO = s.REF_NO 
AND s.TR_DATE >= (
    SELECT s.TR_DATE 
    FROM sldtl AS s 
    ORDER BY s.TR_DATE DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
GROUP BY s.TR_DATE DESC, s.TR_CODE, s.TR_CTLNO
```

PS: I did not read your rest of SQL

Comment: OOPS exactly same answer by 1000111 :)

Comment: thank you so much for your time sir. God bless you always. :D