# How to correct the "Balance" per transaction. Group by Date DESC

Tags: mysql

Good day, I need your help guys so that I can generate the correct data in "BALANCE" column for every transaction in "Descending" order of the transaction date.

```
SELECT 
t.TR_DATE
t.DEBIT,
t.CREDIT,
@balance := @balance + t.DEBIT - t.CREDIT AS BALANCE
FROM 
(
  SELECT s.TR_DATE AS TR_DATE,
         SUM(IF(s.AMT>0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) AS DEBIT,
         SUM(IF(s.AMT<0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) * -1 AS CREDIT
  FROM
    sldtl AS s
  LEFT JOIN
    transtype
  ON
    transtype.TransTypeID = s.TR_CODE
  WHERE
    s.SL_BRCODE= 1 AND s.SL_CLIENTID= 267 AND s.SLC_CODE= 13 AND s.SLT_CODE= 15 AND 
    s.REF_NO= s.REF_NO AND s.TR_DATE <= CURDATE()
    GROUP BY
    s.TR_DATE DESC, s.TR_CODE, s.TR_CTLNO 
) AS t , (SELECT @balance := 0) var;
```

Result of the query above with "ASC" order of the transaction date

```
Accounts Payable    
**Note in this Accounts Debit is a deduction.
Date of Deposit: 2011-12-31 
Initial amount 79,799.44 as of 2011-12-31

+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Trans Date |    Debit    |     Credit    |    Balance  |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| 2011-12-31 |        0.00 |     79,799.44 |   79,799.44 |->First Trans date
| 2012-01-15 |        0.00 |       560.27  |   80,359.71 |
| 2012-01-31 |        0.00 |       500.00  |   80,859.71 |
| .......... |    ........ |   ........... | ........... |
| .......... |    ........ |   ........... | ........... |
| .......... |    ........ |   ........... | ........... |
| .......... |    ........ |   ........... | ........... |
| 2016-03-15 |        0.00 |     1,000.00  |   92,218.37 |
| 2016-03-30 |        0.00 |     1,000.00  |   93,218.37 |
| 2016-04-06 |   30,000.00 |         0.00  |   63,218.37 |->Last Trans date
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

When I replace the "ASC" to "DESC" the balance will become the amount of the last transaction. like debit=30,000, balance=30,000 also.

"DESC" order of transaction date. Needed Result.

```
Accounts Payable    
**Note in this Accounts Debit is a deduction.
Date of Deposit: 2011-12-31 
Initial amount 79,799.44 as of 2011-12-31
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Trans Date |    Debit    |     Credit    |    Balance  |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| 2016-04-06 |   30,000.00 |         0.00  |   63,218.37 |->Last Trans date
| 2016-03-30 |        0.00 |     1,000.00  |   93,218.37 |
| 2016-03-15 |        0.00 |     1,000.00  |   92,218.37 |
| .......... |    ........ |   ........... | ........... |
| .......... |    ........ |   ........... | ........... |
| .......... |    ........ |   ........... | ........... |
| .......... |    ........ |   ........... | ........... |
| 2012-01-31 |        0.00 |       500.00  |   80,859.71 |
| 2012-01-15 |        0.00 |       560.27  |   80,359.71 |
| 2011-12-31 |        0.00 |     79,799.44 |   79,799.44 |->First Trans date
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Edited with TR_DATE

Comment: What happens when you change `DESC` to `ASC` ?

Comment: the last amount will become the balance. like Debit 30,000 the balance is also 30,000 instead of the  63,218.37

Comment: Try putting an `ORDER BY` clause here:  `) AS t , (SELECT @balance := 0) var ORDER BY [Trans Date] ASC;`

Comment: nothing was changed sir. the result is the same to the query above

Comment: The first resultant table is the output you are getting right now by the above query? And you want sort this output in descending order of date? That's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a discussion I finally came with this:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        t.TR_DATE
        t.DEBIT,
        t.CREDIT,
        @balance := @balance + t.DEBIT - t.CREDIT AS BALANCE
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT s.TR_DATE AS TR_DATE,
                     SUM(IF(s.AMT>0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) AS DEBIT,
                     SUM(IF(s.AMT<0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) * -1 AS CREDIT
        FROM
            sldtl AS s
        LEFT JOIN
            transtype
        ON
            transtype.TransTypeID = s.TR_CODE
        WHERE
            s.SL_BRCODE= 1 AND s.SL_CLIENTID= 267 AND s.SLC_CODE= 13 AND s.SLT_CODE= 15 AND 
            s.REF_NO= s.REF_NO AND s.TR_DATE <= CURDATE()
            GROUP BY
            s.TR_DATE ASC, s.TR_CODE, s.TR_CTLNO 
    ) AS t , (SELECT @balance := 0) var
) firstTableOutput
ORDER BY firstTableOutput.TR_DATE DESC;
```

**Note:**

- `GROUPING BY s.TR_DATE` in **ascending** order.
- Then make an **alias** of the table.
- And finally sort the alias table's output in **descending** order.

Comment: Sir the date is in Descending order. But the expected result that I want in the is like this 
2016-04-06 |   30,000.00 |    0.00  |   63,218.37 |->Last Trans date.  In the 2nd table that's the result that I need. is it possible to generate a result like that sir?

Comment: What's the result right now you are getting from this query?

Comment: 2016-04-06 | 30,000.00 | 0.00 |30,000.00 | the 1st result of debit column

Comment: Can you share a fiddle with your sample data? [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/). Otherwise it's tough to debug what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry if I take so much time to give you this sir. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b1197/1

Comment: No sir, thats the result of the query that you revise yesterday. I want it to order the date to DESC, the expected result that i want is  2016-04-06 |   30,000.00 |  0.00  |   63,218.37 | generate the last total amount of the transaction

Comment: refer this |2016-04-06 | 30,000.00 | 0.00 | 63,218.37 | data in the 2nd table below,  my question. is it possible sir to generate this data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115365/discussion-between-1000111-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

Use the whole query as a sub query and order by `tr_date desc`. I've modified the query but the one you've given seems incomplete. I don't see a date column selected in your select query.

```
 select A.* from (

  SELECT 
  t.tr_date
  t.DEBIT,
  t.CREDIT,
  @balance := @balance + t.DEBIT - t.CREDIT AS BALANCE
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT tr_Date, SUM(IF(s.AMT>0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) AS DEBIT,
               SUM(IF(s.AMT<0 AND s.SLE_CODE=11,s.AMT,0)) * -1 AS CREDIT
    FROM
      sldtl AS s
    LEFT JOIN
      transtype
    ON
      transtype.TransTypeID = s.TR_CODE
    WHERE
      s.SL_BRCODE= 1 AND s.SL_CLIENTID= 267 AND s.SLC_CODE= 13 AND s.SLT_CODE= 15 AND 
      s.REF_NO= s.REF_NO AND s.TR_DATE <= CURDATE()
      GROUP BY
      s.TR_DATE DESC, s.TR_CODE, s.TR_CTLNO 
  ) AS t , (SELECT @balance := 0) var;  

 ) A order by A.tr_date desc
```

Comment: sorry i didn't notice. I just shorten the select query. ill try to edit and put the s.TR_DATE to the select query.

Comment: no, sir it will just return the last transaction amount like debit 30k, balance is also 30k. instead of the current total amount